# Can someone explain splitting list elements based on comparison to another list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So say I have two lists that contain the same string but split differently:

```
sentences = ["This is a sentence", "so is this"]
phrases = ["This is", "a sentence so", "is this"]
```

What I am trying to do is check whether any element of the 'phrases' list is not fully represented by one of the elements in sentences, and then split this 'phrases' element accordingly. For example, in this case:

```
"a sentence so"
```

in 'phrases' is represented partly in both elements 1 and 2 in 'sentences' and so should be split between "a sentence" and "so" in order to create a new element.

"This is" and "is this" in 'phrases' should effectively be ignored, as they each correspond fully to one element in 'sentences'. Following this, let's say I wanted to do an element count to determine how many are in each list, the result for 'sentences' should still be 2, but 'phrases' should go from 3 to 4.

```
Sentencecount=0
Phrasecount=0
for i in sentences:
    Sentencecount+=1
for n in phrases:
#code here should check each element with 'sentences' elements and split    accordingly
    Phrasecount += 1

#expected result: phrases = ["This is", "a sentence", "so", "is this"]
```

Comment: What would you want the output to be for this example?

Comment: Hi, so the output for words1 would remained unchanged but then words2 will be split into ["This is", ["a sentence", "so"], "is this"]

Comment: Are you assuming a space between each list item?

Comment: What if `words1 = ["This", "is a sentence", "so is", "this"]`?

Comment: If that were the case, then the split for words2 would follow the same concept, resulting in

    [["This", "is"], ["a sentence", "so"], ["is", "this"]]

I am not yet considering joining the correct words2 split elements if they belong to one element of words1 as such, but please feel free to provide an example of how this would work if it is necessary to the overall algorithm.

Also, space assumption can be avoided as this may in some cases be replaced with, e.g., a newline character

Comment: Technically, the "so" in "so is this" should be capitalized. Does capitalization matter? Should "This" != "this"? Also, how significant is the ordering in phrases? Is it a requirement that a phrase be in 1 or more *adjacent* sentences, or can the phrase take words from multiple, arbitrary sentences?

Comment: Hi, capitalization is not an issue. As for your adjacency query, the answer is yes, as the sentences are the same but split differently so essentially it has to be a phrase that appears partly in one sentence and the rest in the next sentence.

Comment: In that case, just enumerate the sentences and use that as sentence_id. Break phrases when words change sentence_id.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, this was harder -- and more fun! -- than I expected.

```
from collections import deque

def align_wordlists(words1, words2):
    # Split every element of the word lists
    # >>> [e.split(" ") for e in ["This is", "a sentence"]]
    # [["This", "is"], ["a", "sentence"]]
    words1_split = [e.split(" ") for e in words1]
    words2_split = [e.split(" ") for e in words2]

    # Assert that the flattened lists are identical
    assert [word for split in words1_split for word in split] == \
            [word for split in words2_split for word in split]

    # Create a queue and two tracking lists
    Q = deque(enumerate(words2_split))
    result = []
    splits = []

    # Keep track of the current sublist in words1
    words1_sublist_id = 0
    words1_sublist_offset = 0

    # Keep iterating until the queue is empty
    while Q:
        sublist_id, sublist = Q.popleft()
        sublist_len = len(sublist)

        words1_sublist_len = len(words1_split[words1_sublist_id])
        words1_remaining_len = words1_sublist_len - words1_sublist_offset

        if sublist_len <= words1_remaining_len:
            # The sublist fits entirely into the current segment in words 1,
            # add sublist untouched to resulting list.
            result.append(" ".join(sublist))

            # Update the sublist tracking
            if (words1_sublist_len - words1_sublist_offset - sublist_len) == 0:
                # The sublist filled the remaining space
                words1_sublist_id += 1
                words1_sublist_offset = 0
            else:
                # The sublist only filled part of the remaining space
                words1_sublist_offset += sublist_len

        else:
            # Only part of the current sublist fits.
            # Split the segment at the point where the left
            # part fits into the current segment of words1.
            # Then add the remaining right list to the front
            # of the queue.
            left = " ".join(sublist[:words1_remaining_len])
            right = sublist[words1_remaining_len:]
            result.append(left)
            Q.appendleft((sublist_id, right))

            # Keep track of splits
            splits.append(sublist_id)

            # update indices
            words1_sublist_id += 1
            words1_sublist_offset = 0

    # Combine splits into sublists to get desired result
    for split in splits:
        if isinstance(result[split], str):
            result[split:split+2] = [[result[split], result[split + 1]]]
        else:
            result[split] = result[split] + [result[split + 1]]
            del result[split + 1]

    return result
```

### Examples

```
>>> words1 = ["This is a sentence", "so is this"]
>>> words2 = ["This is", "a sentence so", "is this"]
>>> align_wordlists(words1, words2)
['This is', ['a sentence', 'so'], 'is this']

>>> words1 = ["This is a longer", "sentence with", "different splits"]
>>> words2 = ["This is", "a longer sentence", "with different splits"]
>>> align_wordlists(words1, words2)
['This is', ['a longer', 'sentence'], ['with', 'different splits']]

>>> words1 = ["This is a longer", "sentence with", "different splits"]
>>> words2 = ["This is", "a longer sentence with different splits"]
>>> align_wordlists(words1, words2)
['This is', ['a longer', 'sentence with', 'different splits']]
```

---

## Overview of the algorithm

A high-level description of the algorithm used here.
The problem you described boils down to this question:

> For every phrase in the second list of words, to which sentence in the first list does it belong?

To answer this question, we take a few steps in the above algorithm:

1. Split the groups of words in `words1` and `words2` up into sub-lists. We do this at the start because it makes it easier to handle single words in *phrases* later.

   ```
   def align_wordlists(words1, words2):
       # Split every element of the word lists
       # >>> [e.split(" ") for e in ["This is", "a sentence"]]
       # [["This", "is"], ["a", "sentence"]]
       words1_split = [e.split(" ") for e in words1]
       words2_split = [e.split(" ") for e in words2]
   ```
2. Just to make sure this algorithm will work, I added an assertion which verifies that the two sentences (i.e. the word lists) are absolutely identical if we ignore every splitting and spaces:

   ```
       # Assert that the flattened lists are identical
       assert [word for split in words1_split for word in split] == \
               [word for split in words2_split for word in split]
   ```
3. To keep track of which *phrases* we have to look at, we use a [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.deque), a queue that is part of the Python `collections` library.

   ```
       # Create a queue and two tracking lists
       Q = deque(enumerate(words2_split))
       result = []
       splits = []
   ```

   We initialize this queue with every *phrase* of the second word list, combined with it's index within the wordlist. See [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#enumerate).
4. Since we are comparing the *phrases* in the second word-list to the *sentences* in the first word-list, we somehow have to keep track of where we are and where we already looked in the first word-list.

   ```
       # Keep track of the current sublist in words1
       words1_sublist_id = 0
       words1_sublist_offset = 0
   ```
5. Since our queue is our "stack of work", we execute the following code as long as the queue has items in it:

   ```
       # Keep iterating until the queue is empty
       while Q:
   ```
6. First things first: get the item from the front of the queue. I am unpacking the tuple we pushed onto the list in step 3 during the initialization. `sublist_id` is the index of where the sub-list was in the second word-list, `sublist` is the actual list of words, i.e. the *phrase*. In addition we also calculate the length of the *phrase*, which we will need later.

   ```
           sublist_id, sublist = Q.popleft()
           sublist_len = len(sublist)
   ```
7. Now we need to check if the current *phrase* fits into the *sentence* we are currently looking at. (At the start of the algorithm, the `words1_sublist_id` is 0, so we are looking at the first group in the first word-list.)

   ```
           words1_sublist_len = len(words1_split[words1_sublist_id])
           words1_remaining_len = words1_sublist_len - words1_sublist_offset
   ```

   What does it mean: "can it fit?" If the *phrase* fits into the *sentence*, the *phrase* can be represented fully by the *sentence*.
8. **IF:** The length of the *phrase* is shorter than the length of the remaining *sentence*, i.e.: **we do not have to split!**

   ```
           if sublist_len <= words1_remaining_len:
   ```

   1. Since we don't have to split, we can just append the *phrase* to the `result` list (I am `join`ing on a single space `" "` to combine the phrase back into a string.)

      ```
              # The sublist fits entirely into the current segment in words 1,
              # add sublist untouched to resulting list.
              result.append(" ".join(sublist))
      ```
   2. Since we have just fit the *phrase* into the *sentence*, we have to update our tracking to reflect the progress we have made. While doing this we have to be careful to respect the *sentence* boundaries.

      ```
              # Update the sublist tracking
              if (words1_sublist_len - words1_sublist_offset - sublist_len) == 0:
                  # The sublist filled the remaining space
                  words1_sublist_id += 1
                  words1_sublist_offset = 0
              else:
                  # The sublist only filled part of the remaining space
                  words1_sublist_offset += sublist_len
      ```
9. **ELSE:** The length of the *phrase* is longer than the remaining *sentence*, i.e. the *phrase* **can not** be represented by the *sentence*.

   ```
           else:
   ```

   1. In this case we have to split our *phrase* at the point where it overflows into the next *sentence*. We determine the "split-point" by the amount of remaining words in *sentence* (e.g. if the *phrase* is 3 words long, but the *sentence* only has 2 words left, we split the *phrase* after 2 words).

      ```
              # Only part of the current sublist fits.
              # Split the segment at the point where the left
              # part fits into the current segment of words1.
              # Then add the remaining right list to the front
              # of the queue.
              left = " ".join(sublist[:words1_remaining_len])
              right = sublist[words1_remaining_len:]
      ```

      (Since the `left` part of the split is "done", I am `join`ing it into a string. The `right` part is not done, we still care about it being split up into single words.)
   2. Having split the *phrase*, we can push the `left` part onto our `result`-list since we now know it is fully represented in the current *sentence*. We know nothing about the `right` part though: it might fit into the next *sentence*, or it might overflow that one too (see example #4).

      Because we don't know how to handle the `right` part, we have to treat it like a new *phrase*: i.e., we are simply adding it to the front of our work-queue to be processed on the next run.

      ```
              result.append(left)
              Q.appendleft((sublist_id, right))
      ```
   3. Our `result` list will not include the points where we split, thus we keep track of the splitting points.

      ```
              # Keep track of splits
              splits.append(sublist_id)
      ```
   4. Again, we have to keep track of our current position in the `words1`-list. Since we know that we have overflown the current sentence, we can simply increment the index and reset the offset.

      ```
              # update indices
              words1_sublist_id += 1
              words1_sublist_offset = 0
      ```
10. With the work-queue empty, we can work on gaining the sub-lists on the *phrases* we have split on. This one is a bit tricky:

    ```
        # Combine splits into sublists to get desired result
        for split in splits:
    ```

    1. If the splitting point we are looking at is a string, we can infer that we have not yet had a split at this position. Thus we can replace the item at the splitting point *and* the item after it by a *list* containing the two words. (We are using `split+2` instead of `split+1` because the range is not inclusive.)

       ```
           if isinstance(result[split], str):
               result[split:split+2] = [[result[split], result[split + 1]]]
       ```
    2. However, if the splitting point is a list, we know that we are at a point where we already had a split earlier (i.e. a *phrase* has overflown a *sentence* at least *twice*, see example #4).

       In this case we append the item *after* the list, `result[split+1]` to the list, and remove the now appended item using `del`.

       ```
           else:
               result[split] = result[split] + [result[split + 1]]
               del result[split + 1]
       ```
11. When all is said and done, we can return the result!

    ```
        return result
    ```

Comment: HI, firstly I have to thank you for having a go at this, who knew it could be so complicated! However, as a python novice I really don't understand most of the code you've written, so was just wondering if there was any way to simplify it? Maybe ignoring the word joining for the time being and focusing on splitting in the right place.

Comment: I have not looked further into it yet, so I have no easy simplifications at hand, but I'm very certain that there is potential to make this algorithm easier. Which part do you mean with "word joining"?

Comment: Perhaps joining wasn't the right word. I think for now the focus should be on how to split a string in the correct place based on how it corresponds to words1, rather than joining individual sublists from splits that correspond to the same words1 element.
I.e. words1 = ["Sentence one contains these words", "Sentence two is shorter]
words2  = ["Sentence one", "contains these", "words Sentence two is shorter"]
#after the function#
words2 = ["Sentence one", "contains these", "words", "Sentence two is shorter"]

Comment: ^The effect is that "words" has been split from its original element in words2 as it belongs in the first element of words1, but it is not joined to the other elements from words1.

Comment: I have added a second version which does not create the sublists in the result-list (I hope I understood you correctly!). Unfortunately this is only marginally simpler, since I have only removed the last `for split in splits` loop.

Comment: Once again, thank you very much, but I feel now that I may have overcomplicated my own problem haha. I will try to update the original code to specify more closely exactly what it is I am trying to achieve, as I've more or less got there myself bar the splitting part. Thank you for all your help thus far

Comment: @user7222454 I have added an explanation, hopefully this clears a few things up. Overall I can only recommend that you try every part of this function in a Python session to fully grok what is happening.

Comment: Impressively complicated! Did I over simplify in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want, fairly directly. Based on the answer to my question about adjacency, I took the approach of assigning a sentence id - equal to the index of the sentence in the `sentences` list. I then paired each word with the id of the sentence it came from.

With this information, I processed the phrases, breaking them into words. Each word is compared against the next sentence word. According to you, they should be the same - the words aren't being reordered, just split into different groups. It is an error if the phrases-word and sentences-word are different.

So, for each phrase, I simply started with the sentence-id of the first word, and collected words in a list. If the sentence-id ever changes, then we have moved from one sentence to another, and the collected words are merged into a sub-phrase, added to an interim pool, and the collection starts over with an empty list.

At the end of each phrase, I have a pool of sub-phrases. If there is only one sub-phrase (because the sentence-id was the same throughout the phrase) then I add the phrase to the result directly. If there are multiple sub-phrases, I add the pool as a list to the result.

```
sentences = ["This is a sentence", "so is this"]
phrases = ["This is", "a sentence so", "is this"]

sent_words = [ (id,w) for id,sent in enumerate(sentences) for w in sent.lower().split()]
sw = iter(sent_words)


new_phrases = []
for phrase in phrases:
    last_sid = None
    new_phrase = []
    words = []
    for p_id,p_word in enumerate(phrase.lower().split()):
        s_id,s_word = next(sw)
        assert p_word == s_word, "Text differs in sentence {}, phrase {}: '{}' vs. '{}'".format(s_id, p_id, s_word, p_word)

        #print("[{}] {} : [{}] {}".format(s_id, s_word, p_id, p_word))
        if last_sid is None:
            last_sid = s_id
            words.append(p_word)
        elif s_id != last_sid:
            new_phrase.append(' '.join(words))
            words = [p_word]
        else:
            words.append(p_word)
    else:
        if words:
            new_phrase.append(' '.join(words))

    if len(new_phrase) == 1:
        new_phrases.extend(new_phrase)
    else:
        new_phrases.append(new_phrase)

print(new_phrases)
```

Prints:

```
['this is', ['a sentence', 'so'], 'is this']
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, some very complicated solutions, perhaps I've over simplified.
I created an expanded `enumerate` for each word in the `sentences` and `phrases` and then `zip`ed up the indexes. Each unique `tuple` describes the result:

```
def enumerate_x(d):
    return ((i, w) for i, f in enumerate(d) for w in f.split())

def align(sentences, phrases):
    r = {}
    for (i1, w1), (i2, w2) in zip(enumerate_x(sentences), enumerate_x(phrases)):
        assert w1 == w2, f'{w1} != {w2}'  # Py <3.6: '{} != {}'.format(w1, w2)
        r.setdefault((i1, i2), []).append(w1)
    return [' '.join(r[k]) for k in sorted(r)]

>>> sentences = ["This is a sentence", "so is this"]
>>> phrases = ["This is", "a sentence so", "is this"]
>>> align(sentences, phrases)
['This is', 'a sentence', 'so', 'is this']
```

This works with other splits mentioned, e.g.:

```
>>> words1 = ["This is a longer", "sentence with", "different splits"]
>>> words2 = ["This is", "a longer sentence", "with different splits"]
>>> align(words1, words2)
['This is', 'a longer', 'sentence', 'with', 'different splits']
```